# Predict the average stay of customers

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval

This is my data: customers subscribing to a service and more or less regularly having activities on that service.

I want to calculate an average length of stay for the customers using the service.

I have made a segmentation of my customers into a few groups, showing different behaviour. I fit each group to a gamma or geometric distributions.

Typically, the geometric customer will be very active at the beginning then the amount of activity will decrease until fade.
The gamma customers will be only a few active at the beginning then increase its activity to a peak before to slowly decreasing until fade.

I calculate the mean of the fitted distribution for each of the groups. This I what I called my average stay for the group.
For each group, I now can define a 25/75% average stay threshold.

I do a multinomial classification to get the probability of new individuals to belong to one of the groups.

I use the following formula, for a new customer $x$:

$$ AvgStay(x) = \sum_{g \in G} P(x \in g) * AvgStay(g) $$

with $G = \{groups \}$

to give me the average length stay of a customer.

Is it possible to do something with the different confidence interval?

Like to get the 25% confidence interval, using instead of the average stay function, the 25% interval function?